# Could not find artifact io.confluent:kafka-rest-parent:pom:5.4.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I am using maven 3 to run the application but I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for io.confluent:kafka-rest:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact io.confluent:kafka-rest-parent:pom:5.4.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 7, column 12
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project io.confluent:kafka-rest:[unknown-version] (D:\Self\kafka-rest\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for io.confluent:kafka-rest:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact io.confluent:kafka-rest-parent:pom:5.4.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 7, column 12 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

here share pom .xml parent element

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-rest-parent</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>kafka-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>kafka-rest</name>
    <description>
        The Kafka REST Proxy provides a RESTful interface to a Kafka cluster, making it easy to
        produce and consume messages, view the state of the cluster, and perform administrative
        actions without using the native Kafka protocol or clients.
    </description>
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your POM.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

In order to build any Confluent project from the master branch, you must build its parent dependencies. You will not find SNAPSHOTS in a downloadable location

This means checking out Kafka source code, use Gradle to install its current snapshot, then Confluent common library, then Confluent Rest utils, and then the Schema Registry (for the Avro converter), and **then** finally build REST Proxy.

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/wiki/FAQ

If you just want to run the REST Proxy, then download the latest Confluent Platform and configure the rest proxy config file to point at any existing Kafka brokers

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to build a released version.

You can find the releases by running

```
git tag --list
```

choose a tag t (e.g. v5.2.2) and then run

```
git checkout <t>
```

Then run

```
man clean package
```